# GIT : Stop a Tracked file to be commit by some user, but continue to detect change and new Version

Tags: git, github

## **The situation is like this**

- I've a Git Repository shared by multiples users.
- In this repository, there's ONE FILE in which some of us may have to work, while others may not.
- But here's the problem: for some reason, this file is updated automatically (it doesn't matter why, just that it should be), with useless data to commit .
- As a result, those who don't have to work on the file find themselves having to commit it for "nothing".

## **So here's my question:**

Is it possible to prevent the file from being committed for certain users, but still retrieve and update it if it has changed in the main branch ? All without having to enter an command every time we commit/pull.

**Or If you prefer :**

- A and B must be able to pull the file with "git pull"
- A must have his file "detected as change" whenever there is a local change
- B must never have his filed "detected as change" whenever there is a local change.
- All of this must not ask for additionnal command everytime we are pulling/pushing

## **I already have try :**

- Git Exclude (but it does'nt work since the files is tracked and has to be pull)
- assume-unchanged (But I have a fatal Error when it want to merge with the main branch)
- skip-worktree (But I have a fatal Error when it want to merge with the main branch)

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Git isn't very helpful in this situation. It's probably simpler for you to change that the file is not updated for those people who don't have to work with the file.

Comment: You can also opt to just *not* track the file.

Comment: [According to the Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#ignore-tracked-files), you should use neither assume-unchanged nor skip-worktree for ignoring tracked files, since Git doesn't provide a way to do that.